# Koa SSE "write after end"

Tags: server-sent-events, koa

I have been trying to implement an SSE stream with Koa for hours now but got the following error when trying to send a message to my client after initializing the connection.

> Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end

Here's how I set up my SSE:

**Client-side:**

```
const source = new EventSource("http://localhost:8080/stream");

this.source.onmessage = (e) => {
  console.log("---- RECEIVED MESSAGE: ", e.data);
};

// Catches errors
this.source.onerror = (e) => {
  console.log("---- ERROR: ", e.data);
};
```

**Server-side (Koa):**

```
// Entry point to our SSE stream
router.get('/stream', ctx => {

  // Set response status, type and headers
  ctx.response.status = 200;
  ctx.response.type = 'text/event-stream';
  ctx.response.set({
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    Connection: 'keep-alive',
  });

  // Called when another route is reached
  // Should send to the client the following
  ctx.app.on('message', data => {
    ctx.res.write(`event: Test\n`);
    ctx.res.write(`data: This is test data\n\n`);
  });   
});
```

The error comes when we call `ctx.res.write` once a message is received.

Why is my stream ended although nothing explicitly is doing it? 
How may I send a message through the stream with Koa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Koa is entirely promise based and everything is a middleware.

Every middleware returns a promise (or nothing). The middleware chain is effectively 'awaited' and once the middleware returns, Koa knows the response is done and will end the stream.

To make sure that Koa doesn't do this, you have to make sure that the chain of middlewares don't end. To do this, you need to return a promise that only resolves when you're done streaming.

A quick hack to demonstrate would be to return a promise that doesn't resolve:

```
return new Promise( resolve => { }});
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! The middleware system of Koa is still rather obscure to me coming from Express. Especially when it comes to the execution flow.

Comment: I guarantee that once you get the hang of it, you'll like it more!